# Como llamar una funcion con argumento a otra funcion en java

Tags: java, android, string

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
String[] TXbuffer = new String[]{"H","o","l","a"};


public void writeAsync(String bufferx) {

    if ( mSerialPort != null) {

        try {
            mSerialPort.write(bufferx.getBytes(), SERIAL_TIMEOUT);

         } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    } else {
        mTitleTextView.setText("Dispositivo Serial Desconectado!");
    }
}
```

y quiero llamarlo desde otra funcion:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.bt2_TX) {
        writeAsync(TXbuffer);

        return true;
    }
```

}

Alguien me puede decir como hacerlo correctamente, por que tengo error!

Comment: Que error tenes? podes decirnos? porque la llamada es correcta...

Answer (score 0):

creas un arreglo de String

```
String[] TXbuffer = new String[]{"H","o","l","a"};
```

y tu método solo espera un string

```
public void writeAsync(String bufferx) {


}
```

por eso te sale error al momento de llamar a dicho método

```
 writeAsync(TXbuffer);
```

tienes dos  posibles soluciones .. según lo que estas esperando enviar al método.

1
enviando el texto correcto de TXbuffer;

Recuerda que puedes llamar a los arreglos de este modo

```
String valor1 = TXbuffer[0] esto es igual a "H"
String valor2 = TXbuffer[1] esto es igual a "o"
String valor3 = TXbuffer[2] esto es igual a "l"
String valor4 = TXbuffer[3] esto es igual a "a"
```

y llamar a tu método con el valor que quieras

```
writeAsync(valor1 );
```

2.
cambia tu método para que acepte arreglos de string

```
public void writeAsync(String[] bufferx) {

if ( mSerialPort != null) {

        try {
            mSerialPort.write(bufferx.getBytes(), SERIAL_TIMEOUT);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    } else {
        mTitleTextView.setText("Dispositivo Serial Desconectado!");
    }
}
```

Comment: pues hombre, puedes colocar writeAsync(TXbuffer[0]);  donde TXbuffer[0]  es igual a "H"  , o   TXbuffer[1]  es igual a "o"   y así sucesivamente.

Comment: jajajjaaja  sorry pensé que eras el que preguntaba ;)

Comment: Y tene en cuenta que si no sabemos cuanto mide el arreglo, un for tal vez sea una mejor solucion para el caso 1 ;)